# Why does Superbrothers: Sword & Sworcery ask for your Twitter Password?

Tags: sword-and-sworcery

I don't trust 3rd party apps with my password, but I'm curious about what [it](http://www.swordandsworcery.com/) does once it has it? Spam tweets? Connect with your friends? etc...

Comment: From what I understand, the game is about connecting with your friends using Twitter (it tweets things ending with the #sorcery hashtag). I won't post this as an answer because I don't exactly know how the tweets affect the gameplay.

Comment: Either way, the tweets aren't malicious.

Comment: Even if it does something interesting with Twitter you probably don't want to trust it with your password if you can play without it. I would research the game more and to see other people's experiences and if the game uses a Twitter API to properly ensure that your password is secure.

Comment: Since I don't think Basic Auth is allowed with Twitter API access anymore, the game 'should' be just storing an oAuth token, but that doesn't mean they aren't storing your password. Doubtful though. If you do end up entering it, you can check it under Settings > Connections and see if it's listed there and revoke it if you want. Regardless, the integration doesn't seem to be anything more than sending out a bunch of status updates which I would guess your followers would tire of quickly.

Comment: Waaaaitaminute...so, this is a site that 1) stores passwords in form that is reversible and thus can 2) impersonate you on other sites? Hmm, nothing could *possibly* go wrong there, nope. (search for "gawker passwords" for a recent example)

Comment: @Piskvor I don't think we've reached a conclusion on if the app stores a password or not. The oAuth token is not a reversible password if that's what you're suggesting.

Comment: @Nick: If the site is asking for my password, I'm assuming it is storing it until proven otherwise. As long as I give it out, all bets are off.

Answer (score 10):

The game does not auto-tweet. All the lines of text in the game are under 140 characters, and you have the option to tweet each one if you feel like sharing. Please keep in mind that your friends might not be interested in seeing the whole game in their twitter feed. Tweeting is completely optional and does not affect your game progress in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you happen to have knowledge of passwords being stored or not?

Answer (score 2):

The game is *very* tightly integrated with Twitter. Watch the [#sworcery](https://twitter.com/#!/search/%23sworcery) hashtag to get an idea of what it's going to be sending out. (And to see classic Twitter users feuding over whether it should/should not do so.)

Comment: Unfortunately the tweets are protected.

Comment: I've seen that a lot of the text that shows up in pop-ups in-game is getting tweeted.  If that's all there is to it, then it's really not worth giving up my passwords and annoying my friends.  I guess I was hoping that it could read from Twitter in an interesting way or something.  I guess for that it wouldn't need the password, just the username.  Hmm...

Comment: Care to add an example @LessPop?

Comment: The link in this answer should be [here](https://twitter.com/#!/search/%23sworcery) (twitter uses # for ajax stuff so it needs to be HTML-ified).  The tweets aren't protected.  I can't edit because the change is under 6 chars

Comment: Sweet they aren't protected anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This link provides a lot of info: http://geraldonascimento.net/sworcery-how-4-four-guys-managed-to-hijack-the-world/

A summary:

The game has flash flooded and managed to get into #2 yesterday on the top charts. Because of this twitter integration.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of that post. It's my best explanation for why Twitter asks for the password.

There are two real answers:

**1 - Technical Answer**
The technical answer is that a twitter application needs your password so it can register itself and tell Twitter.com that YOU trust this application, in this case Superbrothers: Sword & Sworcery EP.

**2 - Philosophical Answer**
The philosophical answer is that asking you for your password is a way of knowing if you trust the game completely.

My personal opinion: you should.

EDIT / UPDATE:

I have since then played the game, and he asks you for your username and password. If you are not used to Twitter clients, they all work the same way:

1 - They ask you to login to Twitter.
2 - Twitter asks that you allow said app to access your Twitter feed and post stuff there.

Sword & Sworcery is sorta like that. Cept its not a Twitter client. They handle that process themselves.

Comment: Doesn't oAuth address the technical issue without me needing to trust the developers to securely handle my password?

Comment: They didn't know how to use oAuth so they decided to ask you for your password gently. Superbrothers: Sword & Sworcery EP is using your password to place tweets in your name. You think? It asks for your password to login.

Comment: Link in answer is dead.